# Using characters in multiple else-if statements in C

Tags: c

Good day! I am a first year student and a professor of mine recently assigned me to an activity to be done by my classmates. He asked me to create a program where the user inputs the first letter of the month and then the output will be the month with that first letter. For instance, if the user inputs the character 'F', the program will output "February". I've tried various things but it won't work. These are the things I've tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char month[100];
printf("Choose from letters J, F, M, A, S, O, N, D: ");
scanf("%c", &month);
    
if (month == "J" || month == "j") {
    printf("January");
}
else if (month=="F") {
    printf("February");
}
else if (month=="M"||month=="m") {
    printf("January");
}
else if (month=="A"||month=="a") {
    printf("April");
}
else if (month=="S"||month=="s"){

    printf("September");
}
else if (month=="O"||month=="o"){

    printf("October");
}
else if (month=="N"||month=="n"){
    printf("November");
}
else if (month=="D"||month=="d"){
    printf("December"); 
    }
else {
    printf("Invalid. ");
}
return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is always "Invalid.". I also tried a test case where I tried to use strcmp function but I get "JanuaryFebruary" as the output whenever input J, and I get only "January" when I input F. The else statement is never executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char month[1];
    printf("Input the first letter of your desired month: ");
    scanf("%c", &month);
    
    if (strcmp("J", month))
        printf("January");

    else if (strcmp("F", month))
        printf("February.");

    else 
        printf("Please work. ");
        
    return 0; 
}
```

Any help? This is due tomorrow so anything will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

p.s Our professor does not allow us to use anything other than conditionals. I can not use loops for this one :(

Comment: This is what happens if I enclose the characters in single quotation marks:"[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Any help? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn the difference between char, strings, arrays and pointers.

To solve your problrem:

```
int main(void)
{
    char month;
    printf("Choose from letters J, F, M, A, S, O, N, D: ");
    scanf("%c", &month);
        
    if (month == 'J' || month == 'j') {
        printf("January");
    }
    /* and so on */
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt "did what you told it", as they say in programming.  Look up how strcmp() works, and you will find that it returns 0 when you get a match.  Knowing that, you can explain the result you got (as well as fix the program).